# Flow Not Creating Account Share Record (Works in Debug Mode)

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, sharing, debug, summer19

I have a flow that is working via the flow builder Debug page, but not when triggered in Salesforce. It worked several weeks ago, so I wonder if there's something with Summer '19 that's causing an issue (the sandbox was updated to Summer '19 after initial config & testing were completed).

The purpose of the flow is to facilitate sharing for Customer Community users. It creates a public group whenever an Account is created and creates manual sharing on the Account so that those in the group have access to it.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Create new Account.
2. Process Builder is triggered: Whenever account is created with the correct record type, launch flow. Passes in the Account Name and ID as variables.

**Expected:**

Flow is processed. First, a public group is created. Second, an Account Share record is created to manually share the public group to the Account.

**Actual:**

The public group is created, but the Account Share record is not. No flow errors are sent via email.

I put an email send at the end of the flow that sends me all of the IDs (account, group, account share), and the odd thing is that it shows an Account Share ID in the email even though I don't see it on the Account in Salesforce.

HOWEVER, when I click Debug from within the flow builder and pass in an Account Name and ID, this everything works correctly.

**PB - Criteria Node**
[image: PB - Criteria Node]

**PB - Launch Flow**
[image: PB - Launch Flow]

**Flow - Overview**
[image: Flow - Overview]

**Flow - Create Public Group**
[image: Flow - Create Public Group]

**Flow - Create Account Share**
[image: Flow - Create Account Share]

Comment: Manual shares are deleted when the account owner changes. I'm not necessarily saying this is your issue, but it's important to make sure your account trigger/PB are smart enough to recalc sharing when the owner changes. Its possible that in debug mode the owner doesn't change and that in a real live test the owner does change for some reason or another.

Comment: @gNerb Thank you, that's exactly what is happening. I didn't realize that my client has other automation that frequently changes the Account owner. I tried to set up a new Process Builder + Flow to create the manual sharing whenever the owner is changed, but it didn't work for some reason. They have a lot of automation on their Account object that I need to sort through...

Comment: I added an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**pasting comment as answer as it was apparently the OPs solution**

Manual shares are deleted when the account owner changes. I'm not necessarily saying this is your issue, but it's important to make sure your account trigger/PB are smart enough to recalc sharing when the owner changes. Its possible that in debug mode the owner doesn't change and that in a real live test the owner does change for some reason or another.